# std::vector sort() on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sorting, vector

I've got a program that I'm writing on Windows where I use the sort function of std::vector. It works fine, but when I compile on Linux, I get an error that says:

'sort' was not declared in this scope

Is there some Linux-friendly version of sort that I need to use?

```
class Bigun {
private:
    std::vector<Other*> others;
};

void Bigun::sortThoseOthers() {
    sort(others.begin(), others.end(), compareOthers);
}
```

Comment: Did you include the required headers? Add your code please.

Comment: There is no "sort function of std::vector". There is `std::sort`, but it's not directly associated with `std::vector`; it's an independent function that works with arbitrary random access iterators. Either way, if your code isn't working, provide us a [MCVE] of the problem; otherwise you're asking us to guess.

Comment: Sorry about that - I guess I thought I wouldn't need an example with a question like this, but I understand why I would. I'll do that next time, and I appreciate the heads-up.

Comment: It's not too late to edit the question. Questions are supposed to form a repository of knowledge for future visitors!

Comment: Good point! There you go! I hope that's enough code to represent the issue I was having.

Comment: The code is still not complete, as it doesn't show includes and `using <namespace>` directives. In C++ `sort` is defined in `std::` namespace (as most of others global functions) and is declared in `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Right, yeah, I wanted to show the section of code that DIDN'T work before Lightness' answer helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function `sort` in `std::vector` [on either platform](https://godbolt.org/z/JRSZ2r), so I presume you are using `std::sort` with an iterator range from an `std::vector`.

This is fine and correct.

The error message suggests two things:

- You're writing `sort`, not `std::sort`. That will work as long as you wrote `using namespace std`, though using the fully-qualified name is better. Moving on.
- You did not write `#include <algorithm>`, instead relying on "transitive includes" — that is, assuming some other header itself includes `<algorithm>`, which may well be the case *by chance* with the Visual Studio implementation, but not with libstdc++ or libc++.

  You should always include the proper standard header to guarantee portability. Don't skimp on includes just because your program appears to work without them on some specific system.

  Do that here and I bet your problem will go away.

In general, barring problems with standard compliance and/or toolchain bugs, *standard features are identical across operating systems*. That's why they're standard.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{5,3,4,1,2};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (const auto& el : v)
       std::cout << el << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// Output: 1 2 3 4 5
```

#### ([live demo, on Linux](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b62462752ce2d9))

Comment: You are correct - I didn't #include <algorithm> and when I did, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: .. a lucky guess!